# how to compare prefixed with no prefix xml documents in xmlunit to get similar result

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

xmlnit does not recognize the following two xml "identical" (except one has defined namespace) documents to be similar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:message xmlns:ns3="https://www.bookmarks.dev/xml/bookmarks">
    <ns3:bookmarks>
        <ns3:bookmark>
            <ns3:name>Bookmarks and Snippets Manager</ns3:name>
            <ns3:url>https://www.bookmarks.dev</ns3:url>
        </ns3:bookmark>
    </ns3:bookmarks>
</ns3:message>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<message>
    <bookmarks>
        <bookmark>
            <name>Bookmarks and Snippets Manager</name>
            <url>https://www.bookmarks.dev</url>
        </bookmark>
    </bookmarks>
</message>
```

The failing unit test comparing the two:

```java
  @Test
  void givenSameMessageOneWithoutNamespace_shouldBeSimilar() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    final var withNamespaceInput =
        Input.from(
            new File(classLoader.getResource("with-namespace.xml").getFile()));
    final var noNamespaceInput =
        Input.from(
            new File(
                classLoader
                    .getResource("no-namespace.xml")
                    .getFile()));

    final Diff documentDiff =
            DiffBuilder.compare(withNamespaceInput)
                    .withTest(noNamespaceInput)
                    .checkForSimilar()
                    .build();

    assertThat(documentDiff.hasDifferences()).isFalse();
  }
```

The differences come in the form `Expected namespace uri 'null' but was 'https://www.bookmarks.dev/xml/bookmarks' - comparing <message...> at /message[1] to <ns3:message...> at /message[1] (DIFFERENT)`...

Any ideas how can I configure the comparator to ignore the missing prefix in the second document?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when generating the no-namespace document I had no default namespace defined in the root element. Adding it solves the problem and xmlunit recognizes them as similar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<message xmlns="https://www.bookmarks.dev/xml/bookmarks">
    <bookmarks>
        <bookmark>
            <name>Bookmarks and Snippets Manager</name>
            <url>https://www.bookmarks.dev</url>
        </bookmark>
    </bookmarks>
</message>
```